# c# or Javascript set window zoom on 100%

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, window, zooming

How do you programatically zoom in on a web page in a WebBrowser control in Visual C# or with JavaScript?

This is my try:

```
if (window.screen.width=='600')
{
document.write ('<body bgcolor="#4FB8CB" style="zoom: 55%">')
;}
else if
(window.screen.width=='800')
{
document.write ('<body bgcolor="#4FB8CB" style="zoom: 75%">')
;}
else if
(window.screen.width=='1024')
{
document.write ('<body bgcolor="#4FB8CB" style="zoom: 100%">')
;}
else if
(window.screen.width=='1152')
{
document.write ('<body bgcolor="#4FB8CB" style="zoom: 110%">')
;}
else if
(window.screen.width=='1280')
{
document.write('<body bgcolor="#4FB8CB" style="zoom: 127%">')
;}
else if
(window.screen.width=='1600')
{
document.write('<body bgcolor="#4FB8CB" style="zoom: 155%">')
;}
```

Comment: That's great you included code, but what's wrong with it? Explain your issue more thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox & Chrome (Webkit) equivalents to the IE-specific zoom property are, respectively, -moz-transform and -webkit-transform.

sample code :

```
.zoomed-element {
    zoom: 1.8;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.8);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
}
```

You'd have to be a bit more careful with Javascript (test for existence first), but here's how you'd manipulate them:

```
el.style.zoom = 1.9;
el.style.MozTransform = 'scale(1.9)';
el.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(1.9)';
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [-ms-zoom property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Windows IE8. The -ms-zoom attribute is an extension to CSS, and can be used as a synonym for zoom in IE8 mode.

Hope it helps you.