# Can a MVC 5 project change browser level zoom?

Tags: model-view-controller, zooming

I have a MVC 5 app, and I need to have a default zoom out. I don't want to use JavaScript or CSS.

Does such a way exist to change zoom level across all browsers?

Comment: why you dont want a javascript or css solution ? like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836167/c-sharp-or-javascript-set-window-zoom-on-100

Comment: Browser can only run script and view markup language . If you don't want to use script it is not possible .

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `initial-scale` attribute of the [`viewport`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) `meta` tag? Note that this is not a part of a standard yet but is already supported reasonably well on mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder had not you try this by setting body zoom atribute:

```
private void webBrowser_getDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.Body.Style = "zoom:300%;";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html>    
        <body>
            <div id="sampleDiv" style="width: 100px; background-color: Gray;">
                Zoom Me
            </div>
            <button onclick="sampleDiv.style.zoom='300%'">Zoom 300%</button>
            <button onclick="sampleDiv.style.zoom='200%'">Zoom 200%</button>
            <button onclick="sampleDiv.style.zoom='100%'">Zoom 100%</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```